# ColdFusion executing compiled Python exe

Tags: python, coldfusion

I have created a python script that genarete a word document. I want to call this script from coldfusion app. so i add this code :

```
<cfexecute name="C:\tmp\docGen.exe" outputFile = "C:\tmp\output.txt" timeout="10000" errorVariable="error" />
```

But nothing happens , only empty output.txt is created. But no result.docx file and no error displayed

Comment: according to this article : https://skylar.tech/coldfusion-executing-compiled-python-exe/  must python script be compiled

Comment: No, you can call `python.exe` and pass command line arguments (e.g. the script name), you don't have to use a compiled Python script.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), set up the filter to include "Process Start" start events, run your ColdFusion page, look at the parameters for the process that starts. Check the command line and the current directory. Open a command prompt in the same directory, run the same command line manually. Watch what happens.

Comment: @Tomalak  i have tried it but it is the same does not work

Comment: Somehow I doubt that you have tried the Process Monitor suggestion.

Comment: no not Process Monitor suggestion. I have treid to call python.exe and pass command line arguments

Comment: I have started Process Monitor and added filter. Then i run my cf page. This is waht i get in command line coldfusion.exe -nohup -ntservice "ColdFusion 2016 Application Server-StartEvent" -startByNTService

Comment: That's the wrong process, the point is to monitor how ColdFusion executes *your* program, not how ColdFusion is started itself. :)

Comment: SOLVED: 1- there were some rights that were missing. coldfuson user had to have access to run pyhton exe file
2- I called the bat file in the cfexcute tag. Bat file started cmd command with pyhton exe file

Comment: Nice work! Can you write a a short summary of what you did as an answer to your own question?